# redirect to login page while downloading a file via absolute url classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I have a private area in my website in which I put some files (mostly archives) to download. Only registered users can download those files. 
The files are uploaded into the folder /writable/public/... so as right now if someone writes on the address bar www.mysite.com/writable/public/..., this person can actually download the file. What I'd like to obtain is to redirect this attempt to my login page in ASP classic.
I've read about HTTPHandlers but for what I've understood they work for ASP.NET and I don't know how to use them in ASP classic.

Comment: <%
const SESSION_USERNAME_KEY = "SK_Username"

 sub CheckAccess(adminOnly)

 'If the user has not logged in, or if the page is designated as Admin-only
 'and the user is not the Administrator, redirects to the login page.
 if Session(SESSION_USERNAME_KEY) = "" or (adminOnly and not IsAdmin()) then
  Response.Redirect("userLogin.asp")
 end if

 end sub


call CheckAccess(false)
%>

Comment: before any output of course

Answer (score 0):

```
<% const SESSION_USERNAME_KEY = "SK_Username" 

sub CheckAccess(adminOnly) 
   'If the user has not logged in, or if the page is designated as Admin-only 
    'and the user is not the Administrator, redirects to the login page. 

if Session(SESSION_USERNAME_KEY) = "" or (adminOnly and not IsAdmin()) then
 Response.Redirect("userLogin.asp") 
end if 
end sub 

call CheckAccess(false) 
%>
```

Comment: in the beginning of page

Comment: in file userLogin.asp U have to set session variable

Comment: problem is there is no page... the url refers to the file to download directly